# I have added mysql j connector with my eclipse. But still it is saying No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Tags: servlets, jdbc

// I have connected mysql j connector but still error. I have put the jar file on lib folder of WEB-INF Directory.

public class TransportCompanySignUpClass extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practice"+"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "haider665");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the jar file inside  WEB-INF/lib instead of library.